# Cardinality of theories, signatures and decidability

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have been searching the Internet for some days, but I cannot find a resource accessible to me about the cardinality of a decidable set of axioms, or, in general, a theory.
If I correctly understand, a decidable theory necessarily is countable and, therefore, employs at most a countable set of elements of the signature.

Nevertheless, I do not think that the signature employed in writing a decidable theory is necessarily finite; am I right? Thank you very much for any clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct on all accounts. Simply consider the signature which has infinitely many constant symbols; but no other extralogical symbols (I consider equality as part of the logic here). Then the theory $\{c_n\neq c_k\mid n<k\in\Bbb N\}$ is decidable.

Another example is the language which has infinitely many unary predicates $R_n$ and nothing else, and axioms $\{\forall x(R_n(x))\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$.

Comment: But what about the odd but intriguing possibility raised in the OP's question of a decidable theory over an uncountable signature?

Comment: Rob, trivially, the theory is countable, so it only includes countably many symbols anyway. So it's really a theory in a countable signature.

Comment: Why "trivially"? It is common practice in model theory to work with signatures with uncountably many constant symbols.

Comment: But for something to be decidable, it needs to be computable, you need to be able and encode it with natural numbers.

Comment: So that is why I said it is an intriguing possibility, because there are richer notions of computable objects than just natural numbers (e.g., see Weihrauch's book on computable analysis) where the inputs and outputs of computations are infinite streams.

Comment: I don't know nearly enough about these topics to form an opinion, sorry. I think that "computable analysis" happens over the computable reals, which are also countable, and the inputs and outputs are computable streams, so everything is reduced back to being countable (although not necessarily recursively enumerated). I do know that the term "computable" also applies to something else entirely, but I can't remember what. If anything, to extend the notion of computable, I'd try to ask about supertasks and infinite time Turing machines, but again, I don't know much about those.

Comment: I heartily thank you, Asaf, and also Rob for raising intresting questions!